# git squash forked repo commits

Tags: git, rebase, squash

Here is the situation where I need help to do squashing.

I've forked as repository. Say MAIN is the main repository and FORK is the forked repository. I did my developments on 'develop' branch in the FORK. I made 100 commits. But before submitting a pull request to the MAIN repository's develop branch, I need to squash it to one commit. I verified that the forked develop branch is in sync with the main develop branch, which means, I have all the changes done in MAIN develop branch after the fork is created.

How do I squash all my commits before submitting a pull request?

I did some googling, and I tried this

```
git remote add MAIN <mainURL>
git fetch MAIN
git rebease -i develop MAIN/develop
```

However, it opened a vim terminal with 'noop' in it. Any thoughts?